# Excel VBA removes leading 0's from numbers

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro set up so that when we add a new name to the list of technicians and their equipment it will create a new row for each piece of equipment (140) by bringing over the product ID. However if the product # starts with a 0 this is excluded. No products codes have a similar code some start with letters, all have varying length so unsure of how to get the 0s through where relevant. See the code below!

```
Sub AddTechnician()
    Dim wsAddData As Worksheet
    Dim wsTechnicians As Worksheet
    Dim wsProductList As Worksheet
    Dim wsDatabase As Worksheet
    Dim techTable As ListObject
    Dim productListTable As ListObject
    Dim dbTable As ListObject
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim combinedValues As String
    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long ' Declare j

    ' Set references to the worksheets
    Set wsAddData = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Add Data")
    Set wsTechnicians = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Technicians")
    Set wsProductList = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Product List")
    Set wsDatabase = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Database")

    ' Set a reference to the TechTable on Technicians sheet
    Set techTable = wsTechnicians.ListObjects("TechTable")

    ' Set a reference to the ProductTable on Product List sheet
    Set productListTable = wsProductList.ListObjects("ProductTable")

    ' Set a reference to the DataSource table on Database sheet
    Set dbTable = wsDatabase.ListObjects("DataSource")

    ' Copy the values from cells B6, C6, and D6 on "Add Data" sheet to TechTable only once
    techTable.ListRows.Add
    With techTable.ListRows(techTable.ListRows.Count).Range ' Specify the range of the last row
        .Cells(1, 1).Value = wsAddData.Range("B6").Value ' Name
        .Cells(1, 2).Value = wsAddData.Range("C6").Value ' Title
        .Cells(1, 3).Value = wsAddData.Range("D6").Value ' Department
    End With

    ' Find the last row in Database table
    lastRow = dbTable.ListRows.Count

    ' Loop through each row in ProductTable
    For i = 1 To productListTable.ListRows.Count
        ' Combine values from different sources
        combinedValues = wsAddData.Range("B6").Value & "," & wsAddData.Range("C6").Value & "," & wsAddData.Range("D6").Value & "," & wsProductList.Cells(i + 1, 1).Value & "," & wsProductList.Cells(i + 1, 2).Value & "," & wsProductList.Cells(i + 1, 3).Value & "," & wsProductList.Cells(i + 1, 4).Value & "," & wsProductList.Cells(i + 1, 5).Value

        ' Split the combinedValues and add them to the Database table in separate columns
        Dim dataArray As Variant
        dataArray = Split(combinedValues, ",")

        Dim dbRow As ListRow
        Set dbRow = dbTable.ListRows.Add
        ' Loop through the elements of dataArray
        For j = 1 To dbRow.Range.Columns.Count
            If j <= UBound(dataArray) + 1 Then ' Check if j is within bounds of dataArray
                dbRow.Range(1, j).Value = dataArray(j - 1)
            Else
                ' Handle the case where j exceeds the bounds of dataArray
                ' You might want to add an error message or handle it differently
            End If
        Next j
    Next i

    ' Display a message box for successful data addition
    MsgBox "User has been created and added to the Database.", vbInformation + vbOKOnly, "Data Addition Result"
End Sub
```

I haven't tried anything yet as I am a bit of a novice in VBA - most of this was written by CHatGPT ;)

Comment: Please share sample data. [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) Where is `product ID` ?

Comment: You need to format the output cell as TEXT BEFORE posting the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answered my own question by putting quotes around the values:

```
combinedValues = "'" & wsAddData.Range("B6").Value & "," & "'" & wsAddData.Range("C6").Value & "," & "'" & wsAddData.Range("D6").Value & "," & "'" & wsProductList.Cells(i + 1, 1).Value & "," & "'" & wsProductList.Cells(i + 1, 2).Value & "," & "'" & wsProductList.Cells(i + 1, 3).Value & "," & "'" & wsProductList.Cells(i + 1, 4).Value & "," & "'" & wsProductList.Cells(i + 1, 5).Value

    ' Split the combinedValues and add them to the Database table in separate columns
```

Answer (score 0):

This formula removes all leading 0's of a string. This can be applied in VBA with the WorksheetFunction prefix of all the functions in the formula. If a string variable is used then the reference to the cell (E10) has to be replaced with the variable.

```
=MID(E10,MATCH(TRUE,IF(MID(E10,SEQUENCE(1,LEN(E10),1,1),1)<>"0",TRUE,FALSE),0),LEN(E10))
```